# How to get via route details in here map route?

Tags: here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

I am able to get the following details from route object like :
route duration,route length and eta etc..

Route route = routeResultList.get(position).getRoute();
int routeDuration = route.getTtaExcludingTraffic(Route.WHOLE_ROUTE).getDuration();
int routeLength = mapRoute.getRoute().getLength();

Similarly I want to get via route details as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of getManeuvers() method to get the complete details of the via route details.

java.util.List    getManeuvers()
Gets the list of all maneuvers that travelers will encounter along the route.

Please refer the below API reference,  for the different methods available  for  Route class object.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.18/api_reference_java/index.html